# How do Billy and his friends go to the Rock of Eternity at the end?

Tags: plot-explanation, dc-extended-universe, shazam

Before Billy Batson gets his powers, there are two ways to reach the Rock of Eternity, as seen in the movie.

- Being summoned by the ancient wizard Shazam
- Using hieroglyph-like symbols to create a magical entrance

The first method is the only one used until Thaddeus Sivana discovers the alternative.

The first time Billy is at the Rock of Eternity, it's due to the wizard. The second time is when Sivana blackmails him with his family's safety and opens a new entrance. The third time is at the end of the movie when the Shazam-ified kids go to put back the Eye of Sin. My question is, how do they go there? They couldn't have learnt the symbols to create an entrance. So, does it have something to do with the Shazam powers? Do the people with powers automatically know the location of the place or are they able to create doorways with their powers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Among the six powers Billy received from the wizard, one is the Power of Zeus. Besides, controlling lightening, this power also allows him to  teleport from/to Rock of Eternity or to/from somewhere else.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_Marvel_(DC_Comics)#Powers_and_abilities),

> Zeus' power, besides fueling the magic thunderbolt that transforms Captain Marvel/Shazam, also greatly enhances Captain Marvel/Shazam's other physical and mental abilities, including his five senses, and grants him resistance against all magic spells and attacks. The hero can use the lightning bolt as a weapon by dodging it and allowing it to strike an opponent or other target. The magic lightning has several uses, such as creating apparatus, restoring damage done to the hero, and providing fuel for magic spells. **It allows him to travel to the Rock of Eternity, thus allowing interdimensional and time travel.**

From [Screenrant](https://screenrant.com/shazam-movie-origin-powers-wizard-explained/2/),

> **Shazam can also use the lightning to teleport, either to the Rock of Eternity or elsewhere, if he chooses not to fly.** Billy harness all of his abilities in Shazam!, but he doesn't necessarily gain control of all his superpowers.

So, to answer your questions,

**how do they go there?**

He used Zeus' power to go there.

**So, does it have something to do with the Shazam powers? Do the people with powers automatically know the location of the place or are they able to create doorways with their powers?**

Yes, it does. From movie, it seems they have to know the location of the place. As we can see in the movie, when they were stuck in the Rock of Eternity, they asked Billy AKA Shazam to imagine a place, so he thinks of a bar where they get teleported to. Although, we didn't see any specific doorways created for teleportation, it is safe to assume they don't have to create one.

Answer (score 5):

**The same way** they get back from the Rock of Eternity: Shazam powers.

When they were not able to find the doorway back to the real world from the Rock of Eternity, Freddy asked Billy how he got back before and he said something like he thought of the subway train.

And he did it again and he thought of a weird bar and they all reached there.

So it's feasible to imagine that he can do the reverse too.

Comment: So as long as he thinks about a location, he can go there?

Comment: @Matte, for now, it worked only between Rock of Eternity and our world. As he never used for any other travel

Comment: Is there any proof of such power?

Comment: @zero-one did you watch the film? I described the scene and how it happen

Comment: @AnkitSharma Yes, I did. But I feel **`feasible to imagine`** that **`he can do the reverse too`** is too big of a leap to be taken for a community that runs on facts and proofs more than speculations.

Comment: I have to agree with @zero-one that your answer does need a bit more explanation though it's pretty much correct. I checked out other websites and in the comic universe, Billy indeed has teleportation powers. As of now, we have only seen a single proof of that in the movie but we can safely assume that they teleported to the Rock of Eternity, though we don't know the specifics of how that works. Please edit your answer to make it clear and concise. You could edit out stuff like "weird bar" and "he said something like" to make the wording less casual.

Answer (score 1):

##### Any of the champion "Shazam-ified kids" can access the Rock of Eternity through any door they want.

This is explained in *Shazam! Fury of the Gods* (2023), the second film in the series. In the film, Billy and his foster siblings often meet at the Rock of Eternity, and are shown going in and out of it through various doors — a door in their house or even a porta-potty door.

> **Billy Batson** (*addressing one of the antagonists*)**:** You thought you were just goin' into some regular porta-potty, didn't ya?
> [...]
> Anyway, welcome to the Rock of Eternity. Only Champions can get in here, through any door that we want.

They don’t need any symbols; they just have to open a door — any door, and it will lead to the Rock of Eternity if they want.

Screencaps of the champions going to the Rock of Eternity:

[image][image][image]